# Compare PDF files

Tags: pdf, tortoise-git

We use TortoiseGit in Windows. It gives us a lot of value. It is possible to add "External Diff/Merge Tools". Some PLC vendors sell plugins for this.

We would like to compare PDF documents. Seems like TortoiseGit does not support this out of the box.

Are anyone able to compare PDF files using TortoiseGit? Or maybe with an external diff/merge tool?

Comment: Link to part of the TortoiseGit Manual

<https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-diff.html>

Comment: Depends what you exactly need from the tool. Also, a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered